# Opencart SEO rewrite 404 error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am working for someone who runs a webshop. Now the webshop runs on Opencart software, and fortunately they support SEO Url rewriting. I have been trying to get this working for the last 2 hours and havent been able to get it right. I have done the following to the .htaccess file.

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch ".(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteBase /opencart/
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Additionally i have enabled SEO rewriting on opencart and given all products/categories etc. a SEO name.

Now the .htaccess file is located in: public_html/opencart/ so i have changed the RewriteBase from / to /opencart/

Still i get the following errors:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /aquaria/adm-aquaria was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Does anyone have a solution for me?

To give you an example i want the following link: http://aquadeco.eu/index.php?route=product/category&path=94_291 to look like this: http://aquadeco.eu/aquaria/adm-aquaria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, wow i just found out i have been stupid the whole time. I had 2 .htaccess files. One which was the original without the right rewrite rules and 1 in my /opencart/ folder which had the right rewrite rules. What i did now is put the right rewrite rules into the .htaccess file in my root folder and it fixed the problem!! :D

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to put this 
RewriteBase /opencart/

If your url are like this yourDomain.com/opencart/index....    Then
  you will have to put RewriteBase /opencart/
end if;   :)

with your url you don't have to put RewriteBase /opencart/
only /

Regards

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. I tried changing it to just / instead of /opencart/ but still doesnt work. Get the exact same 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

You put your site in sub directory so you have to make following changes

RewriteBase /opencart/ *change to* **RewriteBase /**

and

RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?*route*=$1 [L,QSA] *change to* 
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)  **/opencart/index.php?*route*=$1 [L,QSA]**